# Why symbol ω look like ╧ë, after I returned XML data from my Asp Net Core project to html via IActionResult?

Tags: c#, html, xml, asp.net-mvc, encoding

It's actual only for `Greek` symbols.

Here is how I tried to solve this problem so far, I was trying to pass symbols into this functions:

```
private string decodeSymbols(string symbols)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(symbols);
    string myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); 

    return myString;
}

private string decodeSymbols(string symbols)
{
   return System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(symbols);
}
```

This didn't help at all.

Here are examples, how it should look, and how it works.

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs4EI.png)

[How it shouldn't look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMxEq.png)

Comment: You can't encode using `Default` (which is ANSI for the local locale) and then decode using UTF8. You should be writing the XML file using UTF8 - are you?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thats a good question, the funny thing that i have symbols fine on my local, it looks as i expect. But when i use server, symbols are wrong.

Comment: HTML has special character and you need to replace these character using System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) or System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string).  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: @jdweng it didn't help, i tried already System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Comment: Then the viewer that is looking at the data is using wrong Windows encoding.  When you have ASCII data the codes 0 to 0x7F are always the same.  The code for 0x80 to 0xFF are different depending on the windows encoding which is different depending on the country/language like Window 1251, 1252.  See : https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html

Comment: Learn by example: `'ω'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp437')` gives `'╧ë'` and `unicodedata.name('╧ë'.encode('cp437').decode('utf-8'))` yields `'GREEK SMALL LETTER OMEGA'` in Python…

Comment: `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(437).GetChars([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('ω'))` is PowerShell / dotNet equivalent which could be more familiar to a `C#` person…